# Tapioca failure with sparsam and boost dlopen error

Tags: ruby, dlopen, sorbet

I'm curious about next steps to investigate this issue. I wonder whether this is an issue with the version of boost used when building the native extensions for the `sparsam` gem?

```
/Users/username/workspace/jorb-providers/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sparsam-0.2.10/lib/sparsam.rb:2:in `require': dlopen(/Users/username/workspace/jorb-providers/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sparsam-0.2.10/lib/sparsam_native.bundle, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZN5boost4math7signbitIdEEiT_' - /Users/username/workspace/jorb-providers/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sparsam-0.2.10/lib/sparsam_native.bundle (LoadError)
```

### Command Run

`bundle exec tapioca gem`

### Details

Ruby: 2.7.7
Tapioca: 0.6.2
sparsam: 0.2.10
rbenv: 1.2.0
macOS: 13.2.1
clang: clang-1400.0.29.202

Comment: Tapioca 0.6.2 is quite old (January 2022), have you tried with a more recent version?